# Retrieving info from different website

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I am writing a project thesis and have stumbled on an issue which might set my entire project in doubt. So I just want to triple-confirm before I take any further actions.

I have a javascript file on URL1. The javascript code, for simplicity, retrieves information from URL2.

No matter how much I tried this wouldn't work so I did a Google search and figured out that the same-origin policy might be the reason.

So I ask you again, is this impossible?

Comment: It is not totally impossible, but the URL2 must support Cross Origin Resource Sharing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: or you can retrieve the information from server side aswel.

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet, by server side you mean that URL1 retrieves informatiom from URL2 and parses it to the javascript. If so, that is not an option right now. I will ask my supervisor first.

Comment: @RedHotScalability unless you have control over URL2 (using nhahtdh's suggestion), OR you do it via server-server comms, it can't be done.

Comment: @MrCode, I do have control over URL2. So I am going to try that.

Comment: @nhahtdh, how do I accept your comment?

Comment: @RedHotScalability: You can't accept comment. I post it there just for your information (I don't intend to expand it to some good answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is totally possible, but there are some restrictions to it;

You can access information of URL2 from URL1, if URL2 provides a JSONP way. You'd generate a script tag that loads a js file (url2/information?id=123&callback=mycallback) in which the JSON is put into the specified function (in this case mycallback). The script on URL2 would look like this;

```
mycallback({"json":"information"});
```

Thus, URL1 needs a mycallback function defined and will get the information from URL2

A different approach would be to utilize [XMLHttpRequest Level2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) which can go cross-domain.

Another would be to communicate over onmessage/postmessage and have URL2 iframed within the page of URL1. This goes Cross-Origin as well.

There are other technics to make a hole in the same origin policy, like Hashs (but are very limited in comparison to the above technics)